# matplotlib: scatter plot couldn't connect dot

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I am using the following code to plot a scatter plot, and trying to connect the dot in the figure:

```
   %matplotlib notebook
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
    my_df.plot(x='k', y='score', kind = 'scatter', marker = 'x', linestyle='-')
```

also tried:

```
    my_df.plot(x='k', y='score', kind = 'scatter', 'xb-')
```

But neither of the above works. Anyone knows what I missed? Thanks!

Comment: please give a working example. what is my_df?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `marker` kwag, and remove the `kind` kwag:

```
my_df.plot(x='k', y='score', marker='x-')
# removing linestyle is optional. It does not help in this case
```

Comment: I then got the error: ValueError: Unrecognized marker style x-

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, the code below works:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
my_df.plot(x='k', y='score', marker = 'x', color = 'black')
```